# Query for finding how many clerks,manager,salesmen are working in a particular department

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am looking for a query for getting total number of jobs department wise. Please help me on this. Below is the sample of output.

Example:

```
Deptno|Anlayst|Manager|Clerk|Salesmen
10    |0      |1      |1    |0
20    |2      |1      |2    |0
30    |0      |1      |1    |4
```

Comment: For sample input you can refer default employee table from oracle.

Comment: Great you want people who are going to answer should refer the default employee table for you  instead you providing some sample data into the question hun ?

Comment: Actually the above table given is expected output. The table schema and its data is @ below path:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789485/oracle-sql-sample-database

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Deptno, 
   SUM(Analyst) AS Analysts, 
   SUM(Manager) AS Managers,
   SUM(Clerk) AS Clerks,
   SUM(Salesmen) AS Salesmen
FROM unknownTable
GROUP BY Deptno
ORDER BY Deptno;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sum all columns and set the group by parameter.

For example :

```
SELECT Deptno
      ,SUM(Analyst + Manager + Clerk + Salesmen) AS EmployeesCount
  FROM TableName
 GROUP BY Deptno
```

[Working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/184a5/4)